# PHP require() not recognising/ importing required files

Tags: php, qr-code

I want to import a simple library for generating QR code images in PHP. This is my complete code:

```
require './phpqrcode/qrlib.php' ;
//require dirname(__FILE__) . '/phpqrcode/qrlib.php';

//require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/predavanje_2(BAR_code_QR_code)/PhpQRCode/phpqrcode/qrlib.php");

// outputs image directly into browser, as PNG stream
QRcode::png('Subotica Tech');

// http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/
```

I have tried all of the commented ways to try and import the library hovewere none of them work. This is my file structure:
[image]

The error that I get is: "  Error: Undefined constant "qrlib" in C:\xampp\htdocs... " and " Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "qrlib" in C:\xampp\htdocs... "

What's really confusing me is I have the same code on my laptop and the same file strucutre and it works on my laptop and it doesnt't work on my PC the only differents is that on my laptop I am running Windows 11 and on my PC Windows 10.

Comment: Both the require lines is doing the same. You can remove first require statement and try.

Comment: @PranJoseph I know they do. I left them because  I wanted to show that none of the require methods work.

Comment: But your error says a non-existent constant, not a file incorrectly loaded. Secondly, you need to indicate in which file the code you sent is located.

Comment: @LordF yes the error does show that some sort of Constant is not recognized and that constant is in the file i am trying to import. It's in the './phpqrcode/qrlib.php' directory/file. the constant is actually a class inside the file